# How to prevent a specific Xamarin View up scrolling when soft keyboard is open?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.droid

I have the following xamarin layout schemma:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid>...</Grid> <!-- TOP GRID - This must be fixed -->
    <ScrollView>...</ScrollView> <!-- This must scroll  -->
    <Grid><Entry></Entry>/Grid>  <!-- BOTTOM GRID - This must scroll -->
</StackLayout>
```

iOS behavior is surprisingly as I want(that's a chat layout, so top bar has pic and username which I want to be visible all time), but android behavior is up scrolling the whole page and keeping only Entry and bottom of ScrollView visible, that is almost what I need, but Top Grid is disappearing. Only Srollview and the Bottom grid musts scroll.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT 1**

Sample project:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/46b455cb7148189a0d1f84affa77b7e120210428144025/02b001

Comment: If you are designing a chat page, why dont you use listview or collectionview for your chat instead of  putting inside scrollview?

Comment: @Anand there is a CollectionView inside the ScrollView, it was proposital for avoiding soft keyboard overlapping focused views in iOS. But even if I take off scrollview, android has same behavior, it's why I didn't mentioned the collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this.

The basic Layout structre will be like this.

```
  <Grid RowDefinitions="50,*,Auto">
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" >
                <!-- Username and Profile image -->
            </StackLayout>
            <CollectionView Grid.Row="1">
                <!-- Your COllectionView -->
            </CollectionView>
            <controls:KeyboardView Grid.Row="2">
                <controls:KeyboardView.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,0,0,10" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="0,0,0,5" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </controls:KeyboardView.Margin>
                <!-- Your entry and Send Button -->
            </controls:KeyboardView>

        </Grid>
```

On your PCL, Create `KeyboardView`

```
 public class KeyboardView : Grid { }
```

On ios Create `KeyboardViewRenderer`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(KeyboardView), typeof(KeyboardViewRenderer))]
namespace YourAppName.iOS.CustomRender
{
    public class KeyboardViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        NSObject _keyboardShowObserver;
        NSObject _keyboardHideObserver;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                RegisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications();
            }
        }

        void RegisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver == null)
                _keyboardShowObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow(OnKeyboardShow);
            if (_keyboardHideObserver == null)
                _keyboardHideObserver = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide(OnKeyboardHide);
        }

        void OnKeyboardShow(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {

            NSValue result = (NSValue)args.Notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey));
            CGSize keyboardSize = result.RectangleFValue.Size;
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, keyboardSize.Height); //push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated

            }
        }

        void OnKeyboardHide(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); //set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
            }

        }


        void UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications()
        {
            if (_keyboardShowObserver != null)
            {
                _keyboardShowObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardShowObserver = null;
            }

            if (_keyboardHideObserver != null)
            {
                _keyboardHideObserver.Dispose();
                _keyboardHideObserver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Android add this in App.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="KeyboardSample.App"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**UPDATE 1**

From Your solution, You need to make 3 Changes.

1. Remove this line from MainTheme.Base in your style.

   ```
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   ```
2. Remove this line from MainActivity    `Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize);`
3. Add
   `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);` 
   After LoadApplication in mainactivity.

**UPDATE 2**

If removing `android:windowFullscreen` messed status bar color as  well as bottom bar color, We can make use of custom render.

Create an Interface `IStatusBarPlatformSpecific`

```
public interface IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
    {
        void SetStatusBarColor(Color color);
        void SetBottomBarColor(Color color);
    }
```

In android project create render named `Statusbar`

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Statusbar))]
namespace YourAppName.Droid.CustomRender.StatusBar_Color
{
    public class Statusbar : IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
    {
        public Statusbar()
        {
        }
        public void SetStatusBarColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window.SetStatusBarColor(ToAndroidColor(color));
        }   
        public void SetBottomBarColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
        {          
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window.SetNavigationBarColor(ToAndroidColor(color));
        }

        public static Android.Graphics.Color ToAndroidColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
        {
            return new Android.Graphics.Color(color.ToArgb());
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it from your desired pages `OnAppearing` Like this.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                var statusbar = 
                 DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarPlatformSpecific>();
                statusbar.SetStatusBarColor(Color.FromHex("#112330"));
                statusbar.SetBottomBarColor(Color.FromHex("#304E62"));
            }

    }
```

You can now set the status bar color and bottom color matching to your page.Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I just made those changes, it was good since now I can take off that ScrollView and make things lighter and working properly(I mean, the keyboard overlapping issue on ios). But the original problem of this question is presented yet. Same behavior, it keeps kicking the top grid to out from screen.

Comment: My project doesn't have app.xaml so I added  Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize); at MainActivity.cs, it makes same work, right?

Comment: I just noticed that CollectionView is up scrolling some lines also, so I have to scroll down when keyboard is open.

Comment: @ÉderRocha Can you provide me a sample project? So that I can test from my end

Comment: Sure, this is a cleaned version, only with chat page  https://wetransfer.com/downloads/46b455cb7148189a0d1f84affa77b7e120210428144025/02b001

Comment: Hi Iam not able to run the given sample. Getting exception like  "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'userid' was not present in the dictionary.'"

Comment: sorry, since I already had login data in my device this error wasn't presented, fix this by changing line 15 of file Msg.cs in PCL, change  private int MeuID = Convert.ToInt32((App.Current.Properties["userid"] as string));  BY MeuID = 5;

Comment: @ÉderRocha Ok let me try

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: are you trying yet or have dismissed it?

Comment: @ÉderRocha Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: With your last update it worked as expected. Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: @ÉderRocha Glad it helped.

Comment: one more question, is there any way of letting only Chat Page as no fullscreen mode?

Comment: @ÉderRocha Is it because you want to control status bar color and bottom navigation bar color?

Comment: @ÉderRocha I forgot to tell you. You need to install Current activty plugin also in your android project. Ref : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

Comment: I tried this approach, but it's causing the view to bounce up and then back in iOS when ever OnKeyboardShow() is executed, Can someone help please?